# How do tuples get automatically sorted?

Tags: c++

```
student a = make_tuple(1, "Adam");
student b = make_tuple(3, "Josh");
vect.push_back(a);
vect.push_back(b);
vect.push_back(make_tuple(2, "Daniel"));
sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());
```

Before sorting they are in order 1, 3, 2 in the vector.  After the sort they are in order 1, 2, 3.  I did not define a comparator, and the sort is the built in method with no callback function. How does it know how to sort by the integer parameter of the tuple? Is sorting built into tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples have pre-defined comparison operators. They behave the way you would expect; according to the standard (C++11 §20.4.2.7/5), the `operator<` of a tuple returns "the result of a lexicographical comparison".

Comment: Does operator< look through all the parameters and find a numerical one that can be compared?

Comment: @michaelAdam, in order for a comparison between two tuples to compile, each pair of corresponding types must be comparable (and the two tuples must have the same length). They do not have to be numeric types.

Comment: What happens if the order of matching parameters conflicts? (1, "Josh"), (2, "Adam") for example?

Comment: @michaelAdam, The earlier it is, the higher priority. Being equal moves it to the next one.

Comment: @Brian This is the standard behaviour, but not "the way I would expect". I might expect a tuple of `bool` of the same length, containing the result of element-wise comparison. Or, for lexicographical comparison, I might expect it work for tuples [of varying length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Ordering_of_sequences_of_various_lengths). You don't know what anyone might expect.